# C++ Undefined reference when linking sfml-audio

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm trying to get SFML-audio working in my c++ program.  I'm using Windows 10 and g++ version 5.2.0 from mingw64.  The weird thing is that I'm *only* not able to link sfml-audio.  I was able to compile and run the program on [this](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.3/start-linux.php) page just fine, but it doesn't use audio.  (That page is for linux users, but I was only looking at the example there to try.)

However, when I try to compile this program, sfml_test.cpp:

```
#include <SFML/Audio.hpp>

int main()
{
    sf::SoundBuffer buffer;
    if (!buffer.loadFromFile("sound.wav"))
        return -1;

    return 0;
}
```

using this command in the terminal:

```
g++ sfml_test.cpp -lsfml-audio -lsfml-system
```

I get this error:

```
C:\Users\sudgy\AppData\Local\Temp\ccZW1WAC.o:sfml_test.cpp:(.text+0x54): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN2sf11SoundBuffer12loadFromFileERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What's going wrong?  I would think this was a problem with my installing the library, but the graphical example above works fine.  In case you need it, I downloaded it from [this](http://www.sfml-dev.org/download/sfml/2.3.2/) page, using the bottom left download in the windows section.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you install `SFML` dev files in a standard place? You may need to tell the compiler where the `SFML` libraries are stored with the `-L/path/to/sfml/libs` flag (needs to go *before* the `-l` flags).

Comment: I put them in the mingw libs folder.  I compiled and ran the example I linked to just fine with `g++ filename.cpp -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system`.

Comment: if you found this Q, but you're on **linux:** I had to install the full lib dev package `sudo apt install libsfml-dev` installing just `libsfml-audio` & `libsfml-system` didn't work (cause it doesn't create the `/usr/include/SFML` dir, which libsfml-dev does)

Answer (score 0):

Good news. 4.9.2 MinGW you downloaded these precompiled binaries for a 5.2.0 MinGW compiler. That's why you're having problems. I has something to do with Strings or chars.

Solution. Use cmake to to build from source using your compiler 5.2.0 MinGW.

Bad news. I don't know how to use cmake and stumbled upon this question looking for answers. Let me know what you did. I also have this same compiler.

Comment: I tried using cmake, but I kept getting errors no matter how I tried.  In the end, I switched to a different library.